# Strip or remove tab characters in Liquid

Tags: liquid

I've been trying to remove the tab character using Liquid string filters to no avail. I have content that comes in from mixed sources so removing the tabs from the source won't be a solution. If it matters, this is in preparation for a Jekyll static site.

Here is my liquid script:

`"article"   : "{{ post.content | markdownify | strip_html | strip_newlines | strip | escape_once | remove: '\[' | remove: '\t' | replace: '\  ', ' ' | remove: '\]' | remove: '\(' | remove: '\)' }}"`

You can see here that I'm trying a few things to be able to remove it. I feel like I've tried [all of the filters](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters) and I can't find a way to strip this character from my posts. When I copy this character over to a hex editor, it's 09, which I understand is the Horizontal Tab character. I know that I could likely resolve this issue by passing the html line-by-line, but I wanted to see if there was a small adjustment that I could make to get his to `remove`  or `replace`  this tab character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a little confused but you just wanted to remove the tab character, right?

If this is the case here are few options:

1) Simple remove filter:

`{% assign foo = 'foo   bar' | remove:  "   " %}`

2) Using replace:

`{% assign foo = 'foo   bar' | replace:  "  ", '' %}`

3) Using split + join:

`{% assign foo = 'foo   bar' | split:  "    " | join: ' ' %}`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I had tried this before, but I discarded it because everything else needed to be escaped and it wasn't working. Upon closer examination my text editor was converting the tab character into spaces.